# Setting Background Color of Link and Drop Down Button on Mouse Over

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, dropdown

If user is hovering on a link within a drop down button, how do you set a background for both the link they are hovering on and the drop down?

Currently, I have a drop down menu, and when a user hovers over a link in that menu or the menu itself, it changes the background.

Below are some pictures of the current functionality:

[image: Drop down]
[image: Link in Drop down]

**NOTE:** For some reason my images are displaying as links.

How can I make both the main drop down and the link currently being hovered over have a background color at the same time? If one of the grey links are hovered, that one will be highlighted **and** the main drop down (red) will be highlighted as well.

```css
.control {
  margin: 0 500px;
}

.navadrop {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content .navadrop {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.navlidrop:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/**Change the background of the main link**/
.navadrophead:hover {
  background-color: #DDABAC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <li class="navlidrop"><a class="nava navadrop navadrophead" href=""><b>Dropdown</b></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="navadrop" href="#"><b>Link in dropdown #1</b></a>
      <a class="navadrop" href="#"><b>Link in dropdown #2</b></a>
      <a class="navadrop" href="#"><b>Link in dropdown #3</b></a>
      <a class="navadrop" href="#"><b>Link in dropdown #4</b></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not relevent to your question but `<li>` must be child of `<ul>` or `<ol>` (or `<menu>`)

Comment: Thanks. Actually there is a <ul> tag, I must have just forgot to copy it to the html document that only included the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't style `.navadrophead` background when the element is hovered but when its parent (`.navlidrop`) is.
In other words replace

```
/**Change the background of the main link**/
.navadrophead:hover{
  background-color: #DDABAC;
  border-radius: 5px;   
}
```

by

```
/**Change the background of the main link**/
.navlidrop:hover .navadrophead{
  background-color: #DDABAC;
  border-radius: 5px;   
}
```